# Lauch app from browser

Tags: android, ios, ruby, integration-testing, appium

I want to use Appium to test an app that needs to be launched from the browser via an URL scheme.

What would be the way to proceed? I assume I should not use the 'app' capability with the app path since I do not want the app to be launched right after the test starts.

Code example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check  [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)

Configure app to listen to subdomain:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
  <data android:scheme="appname"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

add link to website

[market://details?id=com.example.app](http://link)

Answer (score 0):

If you testing a mobile web app, then you are not required to setup app capability. But instead you should set the browsername capability as below

```
    // java
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "4.4");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
```

then normal webdriver script should work. Also try to switch to webview context as below , then webdriver commands would all work like any desktop browser

```
   foreach(String context in driver.contexts())
    {
       if(context.contains("WebView"){
        driver.context = context;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to do. I would test the intents through adb. The docs [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/tools/help/shell.html#shellcommands) have an example of what the call should look like,

`<URI> <COMPONENT> <PACKAGE>
You can directly specify a URI, package name, and component name when not qualified by one of the above options. When an argument is unqualified, the tool assumes the argument is a URI if it contains a ":" (colon); it assumes the argument is a component name if it contains a "/" (forward-slash); otherwise it assumes the argument is a package name.`

Our call looks something like this:

`adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "appName://someRoute/someID" com.appName`

Then we just call it as a shell command from our code. In our case using ruby's 'system' command.

Right now trying to figure out how to open the app to a deep link through Appium intents. If you figure this out let me know... (sadness)